# How to represent disease symptoms in Web Ontology Language

Tags: schema.org, data, rdfa

I want to be able to store free text medical records in an ontologically friendly format (preferably owl 2). While I have come across this useful resource: https://schema.org/MedicalSignOrSymptom it is not entirely clear how one could record a set of symptoms.

For instance:

> Patient complains of severe abdominal pain.

Pain, which is abdominal in nature and rated as severe, is the data which has to be recorded from the above sentence.

Where may I find approved style guidelines with which to approach such data?

Comment: Your question/tags suggests that you want to use the Schema.org vocabulary with the RDFa syntax, but then you also refer to OWL. Do you want to create your own vocabulary/ontology (using OWL), possibly re-using Schema.org types, or do you want to use the Schema.org vocabulary for your data, without creating your own vocabulary?

Comment: Following what @unor has said, OWL and schema.org are not at all equal. Schema.org markup is designed for search engines and is far from complete. There is the extension to schema.org markup https://schema.org/docs/extension.html, however, this is cumbersome and does not really add value the same way OWL does. I guess the real question is what is your end goal?? To present data on the web for users or search engines? Use OWL or similar schema for users and schema.org markup for search engines and simply stick to what you can do that is already defined. The schema.org extensions will not help.

Answer (score 1):

MedicalSignOrSymptom is for adding markup to the sign or symptom itself, therefore the name property is the sign or symptom, i.e.:

```html
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="MedicalSignOrSymptom">
  <p>Patient complains of <span property="name">severe abdominal pain</span>.</p>
</div>
```